# How to get content in one page, at the top?

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabularx

I'm trying to make a worksheet in which fractions are compared through area diagrams.

Two questions.

First, why are the contents of this spread across two pages? Why doesn't it fit on just one?

Second, how do I place the contents of the left column more appropriately?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=1.75cm,right=1.75cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{18cm}{C{5cm}Y}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
 \node at (0,0) {2 \tikz[baseline=-0.3cm]{\draw (0,-0.1) circle (0.5cm);} \(\frac{5}{3}\)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{4cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node at (0,0) {\(\frac{2}{3}\) \tikz[baseline=-0.3cm]{\draw (0,-0.1) circle (0.5cm);} \(\frac{9}{10}\)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{4cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node at (0,0) {\(1\frac{1}{4}\) \tikz[baseline=-0.3cm]{\draw (0,-0.1) circle (0.5cm);} \(\frac{5}{4}\)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{4cm}

&

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
 \draw[help lines, thin][gray] (18,0) grid (35,35);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: tex shows you in the log `Overfull \vbox (85.14375pt too high) has occurred while \output is active` your table does not fit in the specified page size

Comment: I see. I've adjusted it a little now, but since the formatting still isn't quite right, I'll put my new code in an "answer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets closer to the right idea. Everything is on one page now.

How do I know how many rows the `tikz` grid can contain? Right now there are 28. It appears there is room for many more. But if I add a 29th row, the document splits across two pages. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=1.75cm,right=1.75cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{18cm}{C{5cm}Y}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
 \node at (0,0) {2 \tikz[baseline=-0.3cm]{\draw (0,-0.1) circle (0.5cm);} \(\frac{5}{3}\)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{4cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node at (0,0) {\(\frac{2}{3}\) \tikz[baseline=-0.3cm]{\draw (0,-0.1) circle (0.5cm);} \(\frac{9}{10}\)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{4cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node at (0,0) {\(1\frac{1}{4}\) \tikz[baseline=-0.3cm]{\draw (0,-0.1) circle (0.5cm);} \(\frac{5}{4}\)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{4cm}

&

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
 \draw[help lines, thin][gray] (0,0) grid (12,28);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{flushleft}

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: tabularx is doing nothing useful here as the tikz is fixed width anyway but the alignment is wrong as you use `m` in the definition of the first column and (implicitly) `p` in the second, so the vertical centre of the first column aligns with the reference point of the second column which is the base of the grid. use two `m` columns if you want them both centred